# how to create SharePoint BI dashboard using SharePoint List in 2013?

Tags: performancepoint, dashboard-designer-2013, bi, dashboard

Can any one please give me an example,how to create reports using SharePoint list using dashboard designer,currently we are using SharePoint 2013.

Regards,
Phani.

Comment: Did you try to select within dashboard designer Sharepoint list as data source for your report ?

Comment: where can i found dashboard designer.